# Changed behaviour for filestream with Windows 7?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I have written a utility that search logfiles for exceptions and it have worked fine with Vista 64 bits. Now I have upgraded to Windows 7 64 bits and it could sometimes hang forever when reading a filestream. I think it hangs only if the log file is active and the user write to it. But this works fine before as I use fmShareDenyNone flag.
I use Delphi 2007. Any idea what I could change to make this work ?

Here is the whole method that search directories for logfiles:

```
procedure TfrmMain.Refresh;
var
  FileData : TSearchRec;  // Used for the file searching. Contains data of the file
  vPos, i, PathIndex : Integer;
  vCurrentFile: TStringList;
  vDate: TDateTime;
  vFileStream: TFileStream;
begin
  tvMain.DataController.RecordCount := 0;
  vCurrentFile := TStringList.Create;
  memCallStack.Clear;

  try
    for PathIndex := 0 to fPathList.Count - 1 do                      // Loop 0. This loops until all directories are searched through
    begin
      if (FindFirst (fPathList[PathIndex] + '\*.log', faAnyFile, FileData) = 0) then
      repeat                                                      // Loop 1. This loops while there are .log files in Folder (CurrentPath)
        vDate := FileDateToDateTime(FileData.Time);

        if chkLogNames.Items[PathIndex].Checked and FileDateInInterval(vDate) then
        begin
          tvMain.BeginUpdate;       // To speed up the grid - delays the guichange until EndUpdate

          fPathPlusFile := fPathList[PathIndex] + '\' + FileData.Name;
          vFileStream := TFileStream.Create(fPathPlusFile, fmShareDenyNone);
          vCurrentFile.LoadFromStream(vFileStream);

          fUser := FindDataInRow(vCurrentFile[0], 'User');          // FindData Returns the string after 'User' until ' '
          fComputer := FindDataInRow(vCurrentFile[0], 'Computer');  // FindData Returns the string after 'Computer' until ' '

          Application.ProcessMessages;                  // Give some priority to the User Interface

          if not CancelForm.IsCanceled then
          begin
            CancelForm.lblLogFile.Caption := fPathPlusFile;
            if rdException.Checked then
              for i := 0 to vCurrentFile.Count - 1 do
              begin
                vPos := AnsiPos(MainExceptionToFind, vCurrentFile[i]);
                if vPos > 0 then
                  UpdateView(vCurrentFile[i], i, MainException);

                vPos := AnsiPos(ExceptionHintToFind, vCurrentFile[i]);
                if vPos > 0 then
                  UpdateView(vCurrentFile[i], i, HintException);
              end
            else if rdOtherText.Checked then
              for i := 0 to vCurrentFile.Count - 1 do
              begin
                vPos := AnsiPos(txtTextToSearch.Text, vCurrentFile[i]);
                if vPos > 0 then
                  UpdateView(vCurrentFile[i], i, TextSearch)
              end
          end;

          vFileStream.Destroy;
          tvMain.EndUpdate;     // Now the Gui can be updated
        end;
      until(FindNext(FileData) <> 0) or (CancelForm.IsCanceled);     // End Loop 1
    end;                                                          // End Loop 0
  finally
    FreeAndNil(vCurrentFile);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The first thing you should do here is refactor out the UI code from the actual logic. Get rid of tvMain, UpdateView, memCallStack, Application.ProcessMessages, CancelForm, FindDataInRow. The resulting code should much shorter and easier to reproduce.

Comment: Yes I agree on this. This started as a quick and dirty tool instead of searching logdirs manually. But it has evolved to be useful both for developers and the support.

Comment: When your application appears to hang, press the "pause" button in the debugger to find out exactly where it's hung. You said it hangs while "reading a filestream," but then you talk about the sharing mode. If the sharing more were relevant, then your program would hang while *opening* the file, not while reading it. The call stack of your paused program will tell you where it happens.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I haven't done this as the computer it hang on don't have Delphi installed.

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers i'd be curious to know how the code could be refactored. i imagine it would be hard to update the view after processing each file unless you had some sort of `UpdateView`, or hard to add each item to a treeview without adding it to a treeview.

Comment: @IanBoyd I'd refactor step by step and start refactoring all these into method calls and maybe pass the method as a parameter to the loop: `vPos := AnsiPos(<<somestring>>, vCurrentFile[i]);
                if vPos > 0 then
                  UpdateView(vCurrentFile[i], i, TextSearch);`

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers Maybe you could update the original question, with an alternate form. The reason i ask is because i see people talking about separation of concerns, but i can never figure out how one would do it without uglying up the code. Here's simple, easy to read, procedure. If i can see the "before" and "after" of a real-world case maybe i can understand the reason of refactoring.

Comment: @IanBoyd I'd need a full working example for that (including DFM file). If you can provide one, please do. Reconstructing that from scratch is a bit cumbersome.

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers Will it wouldn't need to be compilable; pseudocode would work, the *oeuvre*, the basic *mise-en-scene*.

Comment: @IanBoyd please make that a question, link to this question and I will see what I can do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick shot: When you have a file that is written quite often like a log file, you should disable the indexing of the contents for that file. Otherwise the Windows indexer service will constantly reindex that file and meanwhile blocking any other request.

You can find the context indexing attribute under "file properties" - "extended attributes".

IMHO it was not the best decision from Microsoft to enable the content indexing in Windows 7 by default.

Comment: The log-files is accessed with filesharing and is located on a server with Windows Server 2003. I checked it and the server actually has indexing on for the log directory. I turn it off to see if ther is any improvements. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Windows, by default, only crawls the user's files (i had to go in and manually enable all the other locations; i wish Microsoft enabled content indexing by default) - it would not, by default, crawl a folder that a developer would write a logfile to.